# Как добавить метаметод в таблицу, которая уже включает в себя метатаблицу (и этой метаттаблицей является она сама)?

Tags: ооп, lua

Изучаю метатаблицы в lua и вот у меня есть такая задача: имеется некая таблица `t` с полями `pos` и `size`, которые являются массивами из двух чисел - `[x, y]` и `[width, height]` соответственно. По факту никаких `t.x`/`t.y` не существует, но я хочу реализовать некое подобие синтаксического сахара, чтобы к таблице можно было обращаться по `t.x`/`t.y`. Вот как я это делаю:

```lua
local t = {
  pos = {2, 4},
  size = {8, 16}
}

setmetatable(t, {
  __index = function(table, key)
    if key == "x" then return table.pos[1]
      elseif key == "y" then return table.pos[2]
      elseif key == "w" then return table.size[1]
      elseif key == "h" then return table.size[2]
    end
  end,
  __newindex = function(table, key, value)
    if key == "x" then table.pos[1] = value
      elseif key == "y" then table.pos[2] = value
      elseif key == "w" then table.size[1] = value
      elseif key == "h" then table.size[2] = value
    end
  end
})

print(t.x) -- 2
t.x = 222
print(t.pos[1]) -- 222
```

... И всё работает прекрасно! С кодом выше у меня нет проблем, однако проблемы начинаются когда я пытаюсь внедрить эту схему в свой код, использующий ООП. Как вы знаете, в lua из коробки никакого ООП нет, но есть способы его реализовать самому с использованием метаметодов. Дабы не изобретать велосипед, я взял готовую библиотеку [Classic](https://github.com/rxi/classic). Она довольно простая (с виду), состоит менее чем из 100 строчек кода, можете взглянуть [исходники](https://github.com/rxi/classic/blob/master/classic.lua).

Собственно я запутался вот в чём: у меня есть "класс" (который на самом деле таблица из библиотеки, в которой полем `__index` является она сама); у "класса" есть метод extend, который создаёт копию себя, добавляет методы, метаметоды и назначает метатаблицей этой копии её саму. И вот у меня есть экземпляр такого класса. Я понятия не имею, как к нему прикрутить то что я продемонстрировал выше. Как назначить (добавить) свои метаметоды таблце, уже имеющей в себе метаметоды, созданные автоматически, без моего участия.

Ниже пример кода с использованием ООП. Он отчасти рабочий! Мне удаётся сделать так как я хочу, но при этом функционал библиотекии Classic нарушается, поскольку я перезапиываю уже имеющийся метаметод `__index`.

```lua
local Object = require "classic"

local T = Object:extend()

function T:new()
  self.pos = {2, 4}
  self.size = {8, 16}
  setmetatable(self, {
    __index = function(table, key)
      if key == "x" then return table.pos[1]
        elseif key == "y" then return table.pos[2]
        elseif key == "w" then return table.size[1]
        elseif key == "h" then return table.size[2]
      end
    end,
    __newindex = function(table, key, value)
      if key == "x" then table.pos[1] = value
        elseif key == "y" then table.pos[2] = value
        elseif key == "w" then table.size[1] = value
        elseif key == "h" then table.size[2] = value
      end
    end
  })
end

local t = T()

print(t.x) -- 2
t.x = 222
print(t.pos[1]) -- 222
print(t:is(Object)) -- error! функционал Classic нарушен!
```

Прошу прощения что вопрос получился довольно сумбурным и запутанным. Моя проблема именно в том и заключается, что я запутался.

**UPD**: пробовал добавить `self.__index()` во внутрь моей новой функции `__index()`, надеясь что выполнится сначала старая функция, затем новая, но всё устроено сложнее чем мне бы хотелось и в результате я получаю stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, где ещё это рванёт, но вот так вроде работает:

```lua
local t = T()

mt = getmetatable(t)
mt.__index = function(self, key)
  local v = T.super.__index[key]
  if v then return v end

  if     key == "x" then return self.pos[1]
  elseif key == "y" then return self.pos[2]
  elseif key == "w" then return self.size[1]
  elseif key == "h" then return self.size[2]
  end
end
mt.__newindex = function(self, key, value)
  if     key == "x" then self.pos[1]  = value
  elseif key == "y" then self.pos[2]  = value
  elseif key == "w" then self.size[1] = value
  elseif key == "h" then self.size[2] = value
  end
end
setmetatable(t, mt)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы гений! Я пока ещё не понимаю на 100%, как вам это удалось, но буду разбираться.

Comment: Вообще я думаю о том, что не плохо бы модифицировать саму библиотеку подобным образом, чтобы она опционально принимала метаметоды. Наверное так будет правильнее.

Comment: Я всё ещё не могу сообразить, как сделать так, чтобы кастомная метатаблица назначалась всем экземплярам класса.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf  Это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Мне не удобно воровать ваше время, попробую придумать сам :)